# Dynamic multiple select menus showing default SELECTED options

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-select

**What i have:**

I have four `<select><option></option></select>` menus. When a user change the value of any of the 4 (if an option is available) the child `<select>` change there value accordingly. When the child value has no `<option>` values the `<select>` will be hidden from the view.

**What i try to achieve:**

I try to select a default `<option selected></option>` so for example i would like to have to set the default selected option on page load `Windows` > `Windows 8` > `Windows 8 pro` > `Windows 8 pro B`

**The issue:**

When i add the `selected` attribute to the first option menu everything works fine. When i try to alter the other child `<select>` menus the `selected` attribute gets ignored.

**The Code:** ([Codepen](https://codepen.io/crezzur/pen/NWxVqYO))

```js
$("[data-child]").change(function() {
  const selectedGroup = $(this).val();
  if (selectedGroup == null) {
    $('#' + $(this).attr('id')).hide();
  } else {
    $('#' + $(this).attr('id')).show();
  }
  var $childSelect = $("#" + $(this).attr("data-child"));
  value = $childSelect.find("option").hide()
    .filter(function(i, e) {
      return $(e).val().startsWith(selectedGroup)
    }).show().eq(0).val();
  $childSelect.val(value);
  $childSelect.trigger("change");
});
$("[data-child]").eq(0).trigger("change");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; padding-top: 50px">
  <div class="col-3">
    <span>Operating system</span>
    <select data-child="niv1" class="selectdata form-control custom-select">
      <option value="1-1">Android</option>
      <option value="1-2">Linux</option>
      <option value="1-3" selected>Windows</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <span>System version</span>
    <select id="niv1" data-child="niv2" class="selectdata form-control custom-select">
      <option data-group="1-1" value="1-1-1">9.0 Pie</option>
      <option data-group="1-2" value="1-2-1">Ubuntu</option>

      <option data-group="1-3" value="1-3-1">Windows 7</option>
      <option data-group="1-3" value="1-3-2" selected>Windows 8</option>
      <option data-group="1-3" value="1-3-3">Windows 10</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <span>Edition</span>
    <select id="niv2" data-child="niv3" class="selectdata form-control custom-select">
      <option data-group="1-3-1" value="1-3-1-1">Windows 7 Home</option>
      <option data-group="1-3-1" value="1-3-1-2">Windows 7 Pro</option>

      <option data-group="1-3-2" value="1-3-2-1">Windows 8 Home</option>
      <option data-group="1-3-2" value="1-3-2-2" selected>Windows 8 Pro</option>

      <option data-group="1-3-3" value="1-3-3-1">Windows 10 Home</option>
      <option data-group="1-3-3" value="1-3-3-2">Windows 10 Pro</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <span>Build</span>
    <select id="niv3" data-child="niv4" class="selectdata form-control custom-select">
      <option data-group="1-3-1-2" value="1-3-1-2-1">Win 7 Pro - A</option>
      <option data-group="1-3-1-2" value="1-3-1-2-2">Win 7 Pro - B</option>

      <option data-group="1-3-2-1" value="1-3-2-1-1">Win 8 Home - A</option>
      <option data-group="1-3-2-1" value="1-3-2-1-2">Win 8 Home - B</option>

      <option data-group="1-3-2-2" value="1-3-2-2-1">Win 8 Pro - A</option>
      <option data-group="1-3-2-2" value="1-3-2-2-2" selected>Win 8 Pro - B</option>

      <option data-group="1-3-3-1" value="1-3-3-1-1">Win 10 Home - A</option>
      <option data-group="1-3-3-1" value="1-3-3-1-2">Win 1 Home - B</option>

      <option data-group="1-3-3-2" value="1-3-3-2-1">Win 10 Pro - A</option>
      <option data-group="1-3-3-2" value="1-3-3-2-2">Win 10 Pro - B</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By this `$("[data-child]").eq(0).trigger("change");` at the end, you're triggering the options from the first `select` and your remaining selects are automatically set according to your `change` function despite setting `selected` attribute to any options. That's why it's not working.

**Updated:** Without setting initial options in your HTML, you can do this by `jQuery` as well. Just set the other options below `$("[data-child]").eq(0).trigger("change");` this line to achieve your goal in this way.

```js
$("[data-child]").change(function () {
    const selectedGroup = $(this).val();
    if (selectedGroup == null) {
        $('#' + $(this).attr('id')).hide();
    } else {
        $('#' + $(this).attr('id')).show();
    }

    var $childSelect = $("#" + $(this).attr("data-child")), index;
    value = $childSelect.find("option").hide()
        .filter(function (i, e) {
            return $(e).val().startsWith(selectedGroup)

        }).show().eq(0).val();

    $childSelect.val(value);
    $childSelect.trigger("change");
});

$("[data-child]").eq(0).trigger("change");

$('#niv1').val("1-3-2").change();
$('#niv2').val("1-3-2-2").change();
$('#niv3').val("1-3-2-2-2").change();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; padding-top: 50px">
    <div class="col-3">
        <span>Operating system</span>
        <select data-child="niv1" class="selectdata form-control custom-select">
            <option value="1-1">Android</option>
            <option value="1-2">Linux</option>
            <option value="1-3" selected>Windows</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
        <span>System version</span>
        <select id="niv1" data-child="niv2" class="selectdata form-control custom-select">
            <option data-group="1-1" value="1-1-1">9.0 Pie</option>
            <option data-group="1-2" value="1-2-1">Ubuntu</option>

            <option data-group="1-3" value="1-3-1">Windows 7</option>
            <option data-group="1-3" value="1-3-2">Windows 8</option>
            <option data-group="1-3" value="1-3-3">Windows 10</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
        <span>Edition</span>
        <select id="niv2" data-child="niv3" class="selectdata form-control custom-select">
            <option data-group="1-3-1" value="1-3-1-1">Windows 7 Home</option>
            <option data-group="1-3-1" value="1-3-1-2">Windows 7 Pro</option>

            <option data-group="1-3-2" value="1-3-2-1">Windows 8 Home</option>
            <option data-group="1-3-2" value="1-3-2-2">Windows 8 Pro</option>

            <option data-group="1-3-3" value="1-3-3-1">Windows 10 Home</option>
            <option data-group="1-3-3" value="1-3-3-2">Windows 10 Pro</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
        <span>Build</span>
        <select id="niv3" data-child="niv4" class="selectdata form-control custom-select">
            <option data-group="1-3-1-1" value="1-3-1-1-1">Win 7 Home - A</option>
            <option data-group="1-3-1-1" value="1-3-1-1-2">Win 7 Home - B</option>

            <option data-group="1-3-1-2" value="1-3-1-2-1">Win 7 Pro - A</option>
            <option data-group="1-3-1-2" value="1-3-1-2-2">Win 7 Pro - B</option>

            <option data-group="1-3-2-1" value="1-3-2-1-1">Win 8 Home - A</option>
            <option data-group="1-3-2-1" value="1-3-2-1-2">Win 8 Home - B</option>

            <option data-group="1-3-2-2" value="1-3-2-2-1">Win 8 Pro - A</option>
            <option data-group="1-3-2-2" value="1-3-2-2-2">Win 8 Pro - B</option>

            <option data-group="1-3-3-1" value="1-3-3-1-1">Win 10 Home - A</option>
            <option data-group="1-3-3-1" value="1-3-3-1-2">Win 1 Home - B</option>

            <option data-group="1-3-3-2" value="1-3-3-2-1">Win 10 Pro - A</option>
            <option data-group="1-3-3-2" value="1-3-3-2-2">Win 10 Pro - B</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The issue when you remove $("[data-child]").eq(0).trigger("change"); is that it is not hiding the <option> anymore. For example System version shows "9.0 Pie" and "Ubuntu".

Comment: Ok, let me check.

Comment: @Crezzur, I've updated my answer. Have a look at this whether this is your criteria or not.

Comment: Amazing thanks! i have tried the "$('#niv1').val("1-3-2")" but forgot the change() part :D Thank you!

Comment: It's been a pleasure, :)